# Update API response body (data), when data in Google Sheet get changed

Tags: google-apps-script, post, crud, postdata

I have a Google script that get data from Google Sheet and deploy it to web app that generate the API link when I use the API to get the data it works correctly and the response return with the data. The problem is when the data in the sheet get changed the API response does not reflect that change and the response data returned from it was the old one.

This my script code and I have checked that the output var get the latest data from the Google Sheet:

```
function doGet() {
  var standingsSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1kpNP-MufnJkT7Fydh71B6NNA5TC4prnTNi9U23a9UuY");
  var standingsValues = standingsSheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

  var league1 = getLeaguesStandings(2, standingsValues);
  var league2 = getLeaguesStandings(31, standingsValues);
  var league3 = getLeaguesStandings(60, standingsValues);
  var league4 = getLeaguesStandings(87, standingsValues);
  var league5 = getLeaguesStandings(116, standingsValues);
  var output = [];
  output.push(league1);
  output.push(league2);
  output.push(league3);
  output.push(league4);
  output.push(league5);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ data: output })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function getLeaguesStandings(rowNumber, values) {
  var league = {};
  league['get'] = values[rowNumber][0];
  var parametersObj = {};
  parametersObj['season'] = values[rowNumber][1];
  parametersObj['league'] = values[rowNumber][2];
  league['parameters'] = parametersObj;
  var errorsObj = [];
  league['errors'] = errorsObj;
  league['results'] = values[rowNumber][4];
  var pagingObj = {};
  pagingObj['current'] = values[rowNumber][5];
  pagingObj['total'] = values[rowNumber][6];
  league['paging'] = pagingObj;
  var standingsResponse = {};
  var leagueObj = {};
  leagueObj['id'] = values[rowNumber][7];
  leagueObj['name'] = values[rowNumber][8];
  leagueObj['country'] = values[rowNumber][9];
  leagueObj['logo'] = values[rowNumber][10];
  leagueObj['flag'] = values[rowNumber][11];
  leagueObj['season'] = values[rowNumber][12];

  var standings = [];

  for (var i = rowNumber; i < values.length; i++) {
    var teamObj = {};
    teamObj['rank'] = values[i][13];
    var teamData = {};
    teamData['id'] = values[i][14];
    teamData['name'] = values[i][15];
    teamData['logo'] = values[i][16];
    teamObj['team'] = teamData;

    teamObj['points'] = values[i][17];
    teamObj['goalsDiff'] = values[i][18];
    teamObj['group'] = values[i][19];
    teamObj['form'] = values[i][20];
    teamObj['status'] = values[i][21];
    teamObj['description'] = values[i][22];
    var allObj = {};
    allObj['played'] = values[i][23];
    allObj['win'] = values[i][24];
    allObj['draw'] = values[i][25];
    allObj['lose'] = values[i][26];
    var goalsObj = {};
    goalsObj['for'] = values[i][27];
    goalsObj['against'] = values[i][28];
    allObj['goals'] = goalsObj;
    teamObj['all'] = allObj;

    var homeObj = {};
    homeObj['played'] = values[i][29];
    homeObj['win'] = values[i][30];
    homeObj['draw'] = values[i][31];
    homeObj['lose'] = values[i][32];
    goalsObj = {};
    goalsObj['for'] = values[i][33];
    goalsObj['against'] = values[i][34];
    homeObj['goals'] = goalsObj;
    teamObj['home'] = homeObj;

    var awayObj = {};
    awayObj['played'] = values[i][35];
    awayObj['win'] = values[i][36];
    awayObj['draw'] = values[i][37];
    awayObj['lose'] = values[i][38];
    goalsObj = {};
    goalsObj['for'] = values[i][39];
    goalsObj['against'] = values[i][40];
    awayObj['goals'] = goalsObj;
    teamObj['away'] = awayObj;
    teamObj['update'] = values[i][41];
    standings.push(teamObj);
  }
  leagueObj['standings'] = standings;
  standingsResponse['league'] = leagueObj;
  league['response'] = standingsResponse;
  return league;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `The problem is when the data in the sheet get changed the api response does not reflect that change and the response data returned from it was the old one,` and `This my script code and i have checked that the output var get the latest data from the google sheet`. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Comment: The script i made above is used to get the data from the google sheet and convert it to json the i deploy it to web app from deploy tab in the page it the generate an api link that i can use to get the data back anywhere using this api but the problem is when the data in the google sheet change the response from the api still not changed and it return the old data.
when i debug the code the (output) variable data that come from the sheet is the latest data in the sheet but in the api it does not get updated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't still understand the relationship between your reply and `This my script code and i have checked that the output var get the latest data from the google sheet`. By the way, when I tested your showing script using a sample Spreadsheet, I confirmed the updated value from Web Apps when I updated the cell value. Is this your expected result?

Comment: var output = [];
  output.push(league1);
  output.push(league2);
  output.push(league3);
  output.push(league4);
  output.push(league5);
this part of code i check the data in the output when i debugg and it is correct to what in the google sheet but the api that generated when i deploy the response data is old data not the latest data in google sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested your showing script using a sample Spreadsheet, after I updated a cell value, I confirmed the updated value from Web Apps. I apologize for this situation. For example, how about redeploying Web Apps?

Comment: When i redeploy the Web Apps same problem the new api that generated still respond with the old data

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situatioin.

Comment: Please simplify your [mcve] it will be easier for us to understand and perhaps you will be able to solve your own problem.  Create an example that only focuses on the single problem you are having and nothing else.